# Use static token while login into kubernetes dashboard

Tags: access-token, k3s, kubernetes-dashboard

I have setup [k3s](https://rancher.com/docs/k3s/latest/en/quick-start/). Also I have setup [kubernetes-dashboard](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/web-ui-dashboard/) on k3s.

But I want to use static token while login into the kubernetes dashboard. I does not want to use different token each time when I setup k3s and kubernetes-dashboard.

I found [this](https://techexpert.tips/kubernetes/kubernetes-dashboard-user-authentication/) link for using user/pass in kubernetes. Similarly I want to use static token for kubernetes dashboard in k3s setup.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my [findings](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/#static-token-file) we need to create file(token.csv) which contains password/token:

```
 admin123 admin admin system:masters
```

After that while installing k3s we can pass this file:

```
curl -sfL https://get.k3s.io | INSTALL_K3S_VERSION=v1.21.8+k3s1 sh -s - --kube-apiserver-arg='token-auth-file=/home/ubuntu/token.csv'
```

After that we can use the token "admin123" to login into kubernetes dashboard.

Comment: According to my knowledge, the csv file requires  comma-separated columns not space separated columns.